# getPackageName() returns null

Tags: android, resources, android-resources, ui-thread, getresource

I have a method in my android app that returns the **drawable id** according to it's name, this method works so well in the normal cases, but when running it from a separate thread it returns `Null`, even when running this thread on the `UIThread`.

*This method is :*

```
public int get_drawable(int status){
     int res;
     res = getResources().getIdentifier("something"+ Integer.toString(status) , "drawable", getPackageName()); // this is the line which throws the Exception
     return res;
}
```

*And the Exception:*

```
02-04 13:43:14.644: WARN/System.err(594): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 13:43:14.664: WARN/System.err(594):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
02-04 13:43:14.664: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.HomeView.get_drawable(HomeView.java:525)
02-04 13:43:14.674: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.JSONParsing.alter_light(JSONParsing.java:689)
02-04 13:43:14.674: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.JSONParsing.parse_hmm_response(JSONParsing.java:297)
02-04 13:43:14.674: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.JSONParsing.check_hmm_type(JSONParsing.java:218)
02-04 13:43:14.684: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.JSONParsing.parse_hmm_response(JSONParsing.java:170)
02-04 13:43:14.684: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.Login.parse_response(Login.java:143)
02-04 13:43:14.704: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.Login.response_received(Login.java:129)
02-04 13:43:14.704: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.example.solaceap.Login$2$1.run(Login.java:106)
02-04 13:43:14.714: WARN/System.err(594):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 13:43:14.724: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-04 13:43:14.734: WARN/System.err(594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 13:43:14.734: WARN/System.err(594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:**

after doing some tries i found that the `getPackageName()` is the one which throws that Exception, even when tried to statically provide my resources package name it gives me the same result.

`HomeView` is an Activity class in my android app, but the `JSONParsing` class is a normal java class which calls this method from the `HomeView`.

Comment: @MD it's just i defined it as a final String in my app, thx for that notice i replaced it in the question

Comment: Try to get the integer value in string as `Integer.parseInt(status)` besides `Integer.toString(status)`

Comment: try `context.getPackageName()`, pass context to this method and do this

Comment: The question is when do you start the new thread? Maybe the context you get package name from is not properly created yet.

Comment: pls post the full logcat

Comment: What is `HomeView` and how are you instantiating it?

Comment: so at line number 525 in class HomeView, you call get_drawable() ? debug and check the value or print it out for the exact resource name, check package name values, if everything is correct, pass context with status and check if the function works

Comment: this is the line where i get `res` in the above method

Comment: @DoctororDrive kindly have a look at the updated question

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan kindly have a look at the updated question

Comment: @MRefaat you should probably post where do you start calling the parsing thread, what is HomeView and where is it created.

Comment: @DoctororDrive HomeView is an Activity class in my android app, but the JSONParsing class is a normal java class which calls this method from the HomeView.

Comment: @MRefaat it doesn't matter. You probably have lifecycle issues and that can't be detected from what you've just said.

Comment: @DoctororDrive so how to detect that issues ?

Comment: @MRefaat make sure the AsyncTask is cancelled when Context is destroyed. The best practice is cancelling AsyncTask in Activity's onStop().

Comment: @DoctororDrive I didn't make an `AsynkTask`, i just run this as a thread that running on the UIThread

Comment: @MRefaat there is only one UI thread - no need to start a new Thread. Anyway. You need to interrupt the thread and handler interruption correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace says the exception happens in [`ContextWrapper.getResources()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#87). It can only NPE if the base context is null.

The base context can be null if you're trying to call the method before your activity `onCreate()`. You cannot use an activity as a `Context` until `onCreate()` in its lifecycle.

Also, you cannot instantiate activities with `new` as all the setup code involving e.g. setting up context resources will not be run.

For a better answer we'd need to know what `HomeView` is and how you're actually instantiating it.

Comment: Possibly, possibly not - please add the complete stacktrace to the question.

Comment: The stacktrace disagrees with the `getPackageName()` theory.

Comment: i just tried to get the package name in a line before and got the same stacktrace at that line

Comment: Yes, the base context is not set up for `getPackageName()` either. The activity is not properly initialized as a `Context`.

Comment: HomeView is an Activity class in my android app, but the JSONParsing class is a normal java class which calls this method from the HomeView.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
    res = getResources().getIdentifier("something"+ Integer.toString(status) , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Seems most likely: check the value for status(if status=12) and make sure you have a drawable with the name "something12" .

..check package name with context.getPackageName or getApplicationContext.getPackageName. Can pass the context with status parameter to make sure its not null

"res" is null for you so either the context is null(incorrect package name - can try the passing the package name in "" like "drawable") or there is no name of drawable matching the text being passed

Comment: i figured out that the package name is the problem and it's the something which throws that exception, but even after changing `getPackageName()` with my app resources package name inside quotes it just obey the same behavior(runs normally in the first time then throws that exception when trying to access it again )

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("something"+ Integer.toString(status) , "drawable", this.getPackageName().toString());
```

Comment: since the string concatenation operator, every integer to string conversion is useless

Comment: I guess you need to provide `this.getResources()..`

Comment: Try out with the `MainActivity.this.getPackageName().toString();` Where change your activity name instead of `MainActivity`. @MRefaat